# I git-subtree add'ed to the same prefix multiple times from unrelated repos and now I can't subtree push

Tags: git, git-subtree

I'm using git-subtree (https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree) to manage vendor repos in my project.

A while back I reworked the layout of my project and part of that involved deleting some vendor code and readding it using git-subtree from a new copy of the vendor repo.  The new copy of the vendor repo was the same code, but because I recreated it from scratch there were no common commits.

Here are the relevant commits (read from bottom to top):

```
commit df47ba0d6437737473aba206fdc9f2b902fbb073
Merge: 4bc6a27 80b6bb7
Author: User <user@user.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 2 01:48:30 2011 -0500

    Merge commit '80b6bb7ae01fdda2fe7e0c545004136724cbf059' as 'External/Libraries/stlsoft'

commit 80b6bb7ae01fdda2fe7e0c545004136724cbf059
Author: User <user@user.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 2 01:48:30 2011 -0500

    Squashed 'External/Libraries/stlsoft/' content from commit 03149e3

    git-subtree-dir: External/Libraries/stlsoft
    git-subtree-split: 03149e3a4c3289b5a88fc3f7ae17fb11c44c4d68

# Repo containing 6324cb1724fcdf87294b2e4f438dedf5920a3156 is deleted, External/Libraries/stlsoft 
# is deleted and re-'git subtree add'ed from a new repo in the commits above.

commit e235b6c46d10b83c56d5c9f70d2b00df1137fbb3
Merge: 98ee319 79b7a31
Author: User <user@user.com>
Date:   Mon Apr 11 16:09:54 2011 -0400

    Merge commit '79b7a31fe4bc2d5beaca64cd6be0be4d0c971e4a' as 'External/Libraries/stlsoft'

commit 79b7a31fe4bc2d5beaca64cd6be0be4d0c971e4a
Author: User <user@user.com>
Date:   Mon Apr 11 16:09:54 2011 -0400

    Squashed 'External/Libraries/stlsoft/' content from commit 6324cb1

    git-subtree-dir: External/Libraries/stlsoft
    git-subtree-split: 6324cb1724fcdf87294b2e4f438dedf5920a3156
```

Now if I try to 'git subtree push' back to the vendor repo (the "new" one containing 03149e3a4c3289b5a88fc3f7ae17fb11c44c4d68), I get the following error:

```
$ git subtree push -P "External/Libraries/stlsoft/" /f/vendor/stlsoft mod2
git push using:  f:/vendor/stlsoft mod2
fatal: bad object 6324cb1724fcdf87294b2e4f438dedf5920a3156
Couldn't push, 'git subtree split' failed.
```

because the git-subtree-dir matches my given prefix, but there is no longer any commit 6324cb1724fcdf87294b2e4f438dedf5920a3156 and I can't fetch it in because that repo no longer exists.

Any recommendations for how I can fix this?  I can see two options right now:
1. Re-add under a new directory (I don't really want to do this on principle).
2. Manually erase the subtree data in the previous commit that's causing breakages (not recommend to do this in general, but I think I can get away with it in this case since there aren't a whole lot of other copies of this repo).